# How do I store multiple divs with toggleClass in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, toggleclass

I'm trying to add localStorage to the toggleClass function in jQuery, so that multiple divs with the .selected css class stay .selected when reloading or closing the browser. The toggleClass seems to work, but I can't seem to get the localStorage to work. What am I doing wrong?

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo8mmctm/3/).

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('.mix').click(function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('test',$(this).toggleClass('selected'));
  });
  if(localStorage.getItem('test')){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box" class="p001 mix">Div 1</div>
<div id="box" class="p002 mix">Div 2</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this link will help http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvmEbX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uniquely identify each `div` element, here in example I have used `data-*` prefixed custom  attributes. On page load you need to iterate the objects and target the elements on which the value of key is set to `true`

*HTML*

```
<div data-id="1" class="p001 mix">Div 1</div>
<div data-id="2" class="p002 mix">Div 2</div>
```

*Script*

```
$(function() {
    $('.mix').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var lsid = 'test' + this.dataset.id;
        window.localStorage.setItem(lsid, $(this).hasClass('selected'));
    });

    $('.mix').each(function() {
        var lsid = 'test' + this.dataset.id;
        if (localStorage.getItem(lsid) && localStorage.getItem(lsid) == "true") {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    })
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2cksz4ok/2/)

Note: **Identifiers in HTML must be unique**, thus removed `id="box"` and used CSS based on class

Comment: However it doesn't seem to be working in IE8, IE9 and IE10. The items are not displaying and in the console I get the following error message: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference". Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @dlnkprs use `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: Thanks on that one. Perhaps a tricky question, but if I want my users to select all items from the start, I add a new button and function to select it all at once (.check-all) which makes all items get the class 'selected'. The 'check-all' key gets in localStorage with 'true', but when a user deselects something from that list and refreshes or reopens the page, the 'check-all' key overrides the deselected ones, making all the items selected again. Is what I'm looking for even possible to achieve? Many thanks for info!